# "Map Network Drive" Between 2 Servers

Tags: networking, windows-server-2016, windows-explorer

I have the D drive on server 1 with ip 1.2.3.4

I was wondering how I go about mapping it on server 2 with ip 2.3.4.5

I tried entering "\1.2.3.4\D$" and entering credentials "1.2.3.4\Username" along with the password but all I get back is:

```
Error code: 0x80070035  
The network path was not found
```

My firewall manager has assured me that he has allowed access for this one server on TCP port 445. So I don't think it's that.

Do I need to do anything with share access on that specific drive??

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to telnet from source to destination on port 445 ?

If no try to run below command in cmd :

```
telnet 1.2.3.4 445
```

If you are able to telnet try running below code in Run(win+r):

```
\\1.2.3.4\D$
```

Hope this Works !!

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't connect so I queried it again with the firewall manager and there was a "misconfiguration" ‍♂️.